# passing all props with class and stateless component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Are those 2 components below identical? What is the purpose is I'm trying to do a wrapper to customize a component.
does

```
const myComponent = (props) => {
    return (
        <OtherComponent {...props} />
    )
}
```

and

```
class myComponent extends Component {
    const { ...rest } = this.props
    render() {
        return <OtherComponent {...rest} />
    }
}
```

`{...props}`

identical to

`const { ...rest } = this.props`
?

Comment: Yes, but you don't need to do `const { ...rest } = this.props`. You can just write `<OtherComponent {...this.props} />` directly instead.

Comment: FYI, stateless components (at least in my experience with Next.js) do not impose a render override and can be returned directly as the result of your const component method, thus your stateless component can be reduced to: `const myComponent = props => (<OtherComponent {...props} />)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both ways of writing it are identical. Every key/value pair in `this.props` will end up in the `rest` variable.

Instead of writing `const { ...rest } = this.props` you can use `this.props` directly instead.

```
const MyComponent1 = (props) => {
  return (
    <OtherComponent {...props} />
  )
}

class MyComponent2 extends Component {
  render() {
    return <OtherComponent {...this.props} />
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are identical. At first `{...props}` is the use of spread operator to copy the props object and pass it to the other component.
In case of `const {...rest} = this.props`, spread operator is used with Destructuring assignment. Destructuring syntax allows to extract or unpack objects or arrays into bunch of variables.

Code:

```
let obj={a:"1",b:"2",c:"3"}
let {a,...rest}=obj
console.log(a)
console.log(rest)
```

Output:

```
1
{b:"2",c:"3"}
```

Here, a is extracted from obj and is assigned to variable named a and rest of the object is assigned to variable named rest.

So it means doing `const {..rest} = this.props` and passing it to the other component results the same as doing `{...props}`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of components in react

- Stateless Component or Functional component

`const myComponent = (props) => {
    return (
        <OtherComponent {...props} />
    )
}`

> Job of this component is to just render pure jsx!

- Stateful component or Class Component

`

```
class myComponent extends Component {
    const { ...rest } = this.props
    render() {
        return <OtherComponent {...rest} />
    }
}
```

`

> Class components offer more features, and with more features comes more baggage. The primary reason to choose class components over functional components is that they can have state and lifecycle hooks with them such as componentWillMount(), componentDidUpdate()

So, to conclude if we want to render a component who is receiving props from its parent and no manipulation is to be done within their state then we can go for functional component

and about your second question

`{...props}` is identical to `const { ...rest } = this.props`

yes, it's identical!

Hope this helps !